# Spring Boot Application not using Application.Properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and started to explore Spring Boot. Based on the course and documentation that I read, the application.properties will be picked up automatically by Spring Boot. I have the following values in my Application.properties

```
**Application.Properties**
server.port = 9000
server.servlet.context-path=/bharathi
```

But still, while deploying in JBOSS the server port is picked up from the standalone.xml and it points to 8085. Also the context-path is auto generated based on the war file.

```
14:04:52,579 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8085
.
.
.
14:05:20,388 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001 for context '/ou-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but something is wrong. Can anyone please assist me on this?

Answer (score 3):

`server.port = 9000`

This will work ONLY for embedded tomcat sever - eg while using SpringBoot and running just like any other java app.

On deployment server, port is just as configured in the server or deployment descriptor.

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss.... It worked. I was generated a war and deploying it in a JBOSS Server. When I Ran as Java Application, the Application.Properties got picked up.

Comment: You are missing the point. application.properties is picked up always. Its just this particular property have no effect on standalone servers.